# How is a Hex Value manipulated bitwise?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, hex

I have a very basic understanding of bitwise operators. I am at a loss to understand how the value is assigned however. If someone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

My Hex Address:  0xE0074000

The Decimal value: 3758571520

The Binary Value:  11100000000001110100000000000000

I am trying to program a simple Micro Controller and use the Register access Class in the Microsoft .Net Micro Framework to make the Controller do what I want it to do.

```
Register T2IR = new Register(0xE0074000);
T2IR.Write(1 << 22);
```

In my above example, how are the bits in the Binary representation moved? I don’t understand how the management of bits is assigned to the address in Binary form.

If someone can point me in the right direction I would be very greatfull.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Forget about decimals for a start. You'll get back to that later.

First you need to see the logic between HEX and BINARY.

Okay, for a byte you have 8 bits (#7-0)

```
#7 = 0x80 = %1000 0000
#6 = 0x40 = %0100 0000
#5 = 0x20 = %0010 0000
#4 = 0x10 = %0001 0000

#3 = 0x08 = %0000 1000
#2 = 0x04 = %0000 0100
#1 = 0x02 = %0000 0010
#0 = 0x01 = %0000 0001
```

When you read that in binary, in a byte, like this one %00001000

Then the bit set, is the 4th from right aka bit #3 which has a value of 08 hex (in fact also decimal, but still forget about decimal while you figure out hex/binary)

Now if we have the binary number %10000000
This is the #7 bit which is on. That has a hex value of 0x80

So all you have to do is to sum them up in "nibbles" (each part of the hex byte is called a nibble by some geeks)

the maximum you can get in a nibble is (decimal) 15 or F as 0x10 + 0x20 + 0x40 + 0x80 = 0xF0 = binary %11110000

so all lights on (4 bits) in a nibble = F in hex (15 decimal)

same goes for the lower nibble.

Do you see the pattern?

Comment: yes, I see how this part works, thanks for the excellent explanation! So if we have a value of 000011001000 and we do this (8 << 1) this would then leave us with this 000111001000. Is this right?

Comment: So if we had an array of binary 1's and 0's that was 32 bits long and we wanted to shift bit 8 by 1, could we just modify the one value? eg: bin[7] = 1; ??

Comment: going further, if we wanted to do this (8 << 3) would this be right: bin[7] = 1; bin[8] = 1; bin[9] = 1; ?

Comment: how would we code this: unit myBin = 000111001000; myBin = (8 << 1)?

Comment: OK to stick with my example above. If we (1 << 22) to this adress 0xE0074000 which has this Binary Value: 11100000000001110100000000000000 we then get this value: 111000000000011101000000000000000000000000000000000000 being this is only a 32bit register does that mean we now get this value: 0x00000000 which has a Binary Value of this: 000000000000000000000000000000000 ? Have I got this right?

Comment: If you want to shift bit 8 by 1, you can try `num | 0x1000000; num & 0xFEFFFFFF;` Of course, that's assuming bit 8 is 1. You'll have to do some detection with another bitwise AND to figure out if the bit is 1 or 0. Why do you want to shift an individual bit?

Comment: Hi GMMan, Thanks for the answers! I think I am getting confused. I do understand what you and BerggreenDK are saying. I am having trouble with the Register Addressing. Bitshifting is simple, youre right. Its "What" we assign in the Register is the problem. There are several classes in the SDK I need to read up on I think. My problem is, I am over complicating this I think.

Comment: I think I know where this confusion is coming from. In the Datasheet it talks about setting bits in the register (which is not really Bit Shifting as such) This is Bit minipulation! Bit Shifting will change the entire Binary Address as I explained above. There are Classes that can change each bit individually while still using the Bit Shifting techniques. Its in the Classes that the changes are made! Not in the Bitshifting...

Comment: so its just bad english in the datasheet perhaps as "shift" ought to be translated into "switch" instead perhaps?

A gearshift in a car isnt a gearswitch, that might have disrupted the translation if thats the case.

Answer (score 8):

Refer to @BerggreenDK's answer for what a shift is. Here's some info about what it's like in hex (same thing, just different representation):

Shifting is a very simple concept to understand. The register is of a fixed size, and whatever bits that won't fit falls off the end. So, take this example:

`int num = 0xffff << 16;`

Your variable in hex would now be `0xffff0000`. Note how the the right end is filled with zeros. Now, let's shift it again.

```
num = num << 8;
num = num >> 8;
```

`num` is now `0x00ff0000`. You don't get your old bits back. The same applies to right shifts as well.

Trick: Left shifting by 1 is like multiplying the number by 2, and right shifting by 1 is like integer dividing everything by 2.

Comment: The Problem is not in the Bitwise operator. The problem is in the Classes and how the classes assign the information to the Register Address. So in this case: Register.SetBits((3 << 8)); // Manipulates Bits in the register...
How would the Bits be assigned? How does the Register know where and what bits to manipulate? If we know from the Datasheet that we need bit 3 Set to 1, how do we work out the correct Bitwise operation to do this?

Comment: URL Link: [Register Class Documentation](http://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/NETMF/Library%20Documentation/html/73f12956-6a7d-d693-6db8-4ec605c50f2d.htm) Link to the documentation. Its brief and does not give me an answer.

Comment: Ok, A Eureka Moment, Bits of value 1 in mask are set in the register. Bits of value 0 in mask are not changed. So we need to work out the Binary value to set, before assigning the value to the register. So if we want to set 0010011(0)11 in brackets then we need to parse a binary of 0100 to set this BIT! Woohooo finally!

Comment: Great that you found the answer. Please mark the correct one so others can read this question and find it fast. :o) + the author of the right answer gains a little reputation bonus too.

Comment: Remember that depending on whether you want to set or clear bits, you'll need to use the correct operator: OR to set bit, AND to clear bit, and XOR to toggle bit.